# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() or getAssets() has already been called

Tags: android

I am calling `applyOverrideConfiguration(newConfig);` inside

```
@override 
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {}
```

with using below dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1"
```

I am obtaining this error :
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() or getAssets() has already been called**

If I am not using biometric dependency it is working fine without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug in AndroidX AppCompat version 1.1.0. It has been fixed in version 1.2.0. So If you are using `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` then upgrade version to 1.2.0

Ref. : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140880275

Answer (score 0):

override protected method [attachBaseContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#attachBaseContext(android.content.Context)) with super method.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    // copypaste safe code
    applyOverrideConfiguration(new Configuration());
}
```

**Edited**

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
        int uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode;
        overrideConfiguration.setTo(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode;
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: I am already using the same formate but still, I am facing this issue.

Comment: Now it is getting crashed at super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration); with same error

Comment: what is your appcompact version?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.java look into this

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

I was calling this in onresume and got the above error->

```
    val newConfig = resources.configuration

    newConfig.fontScale = FontSize.MEDIUM.scale

    applyOverrideConfiguration(newConfig)
```

Changed to this and now its working :)->

```
    val newConfig = resources.configuration
        
    newConfig.fontScale = FontSize.MEDIUM.scale

    resources.updateConfiguration(
         newConfig,
         baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)
```